# contactos de Google obtener empresa

Tags: kotlin, google-api

Estoy intentando obtener desde los contactos algunos datos, pero no consigo obtener el nombre de la empresa, donde esta el error?.

```
fun getEmployee(): ArrayList<ContactsModel> {
    val empresaList = ArrayList<ContactsModel>()
    val projection = arrayOf(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE
    )
    val where =
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"

    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
    )
    val empresaCursor = context.contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        where,
        selectionArgs,
        null
    )

    if (empresaCursor != null && empresaCursor.count > 0) {

        val idIndex =
            empresaCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID)
        val bDayColumn =
            empresaCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA)
        while (empresaCursor.moveToNext()) {
            val id = empresaCursor.getString(idIndex)
            val bDay = empresaCursor.getString(bDayColumn)
            val model = ContactsModel()
            model.id = id
            model.employee = bDay
            empresaList.add(model)

            println("birthdayList : $bDay")
        }
        empresaCursor.close()
        Log.d(REPOSITORY_TAG, "birthdayList : $empresaList")
        Log.d(REPOSITORY_TAG, "birthdayList - size : ${empresaList.size}")
    }
    return empresaList
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cómo obtener el nombre de la empresa del contacto en Android**

Para obtener el nombre de la empresa (`COMPANY`) de tus contactos, requieres el `contactId` (`ContactsContract.Contacts._ID`) y el `rawContactId` que se obtiene mediante el `contactId`.

Solo necesitas definir la PROYECCIÓN (`PROJECTION`):

```
    val PROJECTION = arrayOf(
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
    )
```

Y la consulta lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
    val contacts = contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        PROJECTION,
        null,
        null,
        null
    )
```

ahora define los métodos:

```
//Obtiene RawContactId.
private fun getRawContactId(context: Context, contactId: String): String? {
    val projection = arrayOf(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID)
    val where = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?"
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(contactId)
    val c: Cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        where,
        selectionArgs,
        null
    )
        ?: return null
    var rawContactId = -1
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        rawContactId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID))
    }
    c.close()
    return rawContactId.toString()
}


//Obtiene el nombre de la compañia.
private fun getCompanyName(context: Context, rawContactId: String?): String? {
    return try {
        val orgWhere =
            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"
        val orgWhereParams = arrayOf(
            rawContactId,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
        )
        val cursor: Cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null
        ) ?: return null
        var name: String? = null
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            name =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY))
        }
        cursor.close()
        name
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
```

De esta forma obtendrás la compañia de tus contactos:

```
  if (contacts != null  && contacts.count > 0) {
        println("Total contactos: ${contacts.count}")
        while(contacts.moveToNext()) {
            val contactId: String =
                contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
            val rawContactId = getRawContactId(applicationContext, contactId)
            val name: String =
                contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))
            val companyName = getCompanyName(applicationContext, rawContactId)

            println("contactId: $contactId | rawContactId: $rawContactId | name: $name| companyName: $companyName")

        }
    }else{
        println("No se obtuvieron contactos.....")
    }
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
contactId: 1581 | rawContactId: 620 | name: Cris Bosca| companyName: Hospital GERMANY
contactId: 1671 | rawContactId: 54 | name: Irina | companyName: San Patricio
contactId: 1673 | rawContactId: 1632 | name: Puisor Romania| companyName: ROMANIAMEX
contactId: 1676 | rawContactId: 1636 | name: Taticu Bosca| companyName: MexRom BUCURIE
contactId: 1846 | rawContactId: 1632 | name: Papa Oso| companyName: Kraft General Foods Inc.
```

Comment: perfecto, pero no se me carga en el movil